# bokeh model does not exist

Tags: django, bokeh

I have django bokeh project and I'm trying to add dateRangePicker slider but I get error in console

```
bokeh-0.12.16.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Model 'DateRangeSlider' does not exist. This could be due to a widget
                     or a custom model not being registered before first usage.
```

This is code for that.

```
date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", start='2018-01-02', end='2018-06-09',
                                    value=('2018-06-02', '2018-06-09'), step=1)

# l = layout(children=[[date_range_slider]], sizing_mode='fixed')

l = layout(children=[[p], [date_range_slider]], sizing_mode='fixed')
script, div = components(l)
print(div)

return render(request, 'index.html', {"the_script": script, "the_div": div})
```

Do I need to add anything in django model?

Comment: Did you add bokeh in INSTALLED_APPS settings ? [if required] Did you do migrations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update: note that starting with Bokeh 2.0, there are only JS components to load (no separate CSS files)*

BokehJS is split into multiple pieces so that users who do not need, e.g. widgets, do not have to load the extra JS and CSS for them. If you use widgets and `components`, you need to explicitly include the extra JS and CSS for them as [described in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components)

```
<link
    href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-x.y.z.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-x.y.z.min.js"></script>
```